# Where's the Events bookmark?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I've installed .NET 3.5 SP1 and I still dont't see the Events bookmark. The compiler was reinstalled few times, still without result. I have VS 2008 Professional Edition

I mean:
[image]

Comment: what you mean by saying event bookmark?

Comment: Yes, the screen is from WinForms, just for show what I mean.
I selected e.g. a button, a window, anything - with no result. I don't know why that happened, why it's not working properly, I know that SP1 makes it visible, but why it's not available, that's a good question

Answer (score 2):

You say you installed .NET 3.5 SP1, but did you install [Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)?  From [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950263/)

> The following new features in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Designer 
>   * Design time support for an Events tab
>   ...

I had a similar problem when I didn't realize that event support in the designer was added in SP1.